# Prove that $N$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Consider the set $N=\cap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1}$. Prove that $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$.

Using the fact that any (finite or infinite) intersection of subgroups is a subgroup I am able to prove $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ and even $H$.

Comment: Using the fact that any (finite or infinite) intersection of subgroups  is a subgroup I am able to prove $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ and even $H$.

Comment: Okay. Then all you have to do is show it is closed under conjugation by elements of $G$. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each given $n\in N$, $\forall x\in G$ there exists an $h_x\in H$ s.t. $xh_xx^{-1}=n$. Now for each $g\in G$, we have $h_{g^{-1}x}\in H$ s.t. $n=g^-1xh_{g^{-1}x}x^{-1}g$, then$$gng^{-1}=g(g^-1xh_{g^{-1}x}x^{-1}g)g^{-1}=xh_{g^{-1}x}x^{-1}\in xHx^{-1},$$Thus $gng^{-1}\in N$.Hence, $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the problem by defining the following action as well. So let define an action of group $G$ on the set of $X$ of left cosets of $H$ by $$g\cdot(xH)=(gx)H.$$ Now try to show that this is a group action inducing a homomorphism $$\phi:G\to S_X.$$ What is its kernel? Indeed, it is:

$$\ker\phi=\bigcap_{x\in G}x^{-1}Hx. $$

Comment: This proof is marvellous. Thanks a lot.

Comment: U'r Welcome. I am glad I could help. :-)

Comment: Well put, my friend! +1

Comment: A small gap so you can use GAP? ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: No sorry I mean my spare time before starting another class. :)

Comment: @BabakS. Nice answer;-)+1

Answer (score 1):

Hints for the proof:

1) Establish that each conjugate $xHx^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
2) Establish that the intersection of any collection of subgroups is a subgroup. 
3) Deduce that $N$ is a subgroup. 
4) To prove normality, use the criterion that $N$ is normal if, and only if, $yNy^{-1}= N$ for all $y\in G$. 
5) Compute the conjugate $yNy^{-1}$. First show that it too can be represented as an intersection, namely of $yxNx^{-1}y^{-1}$. Now argue that each such conjugate is precisely one of the original conjugate, and conclude the two intersections agree. That shows that any conjugate of $N$ is $N$. QED.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but I saw that $N\subseteq eHe^{-1}$.

Comment: Your very first sentence is puzzling. What do you mean?

Comment: Ummm.. Which one?

Comment: Yes, @Grobber, you are absolutely right. What I meant to say is that you should not restrict to $N$ as a subgroup of $H$ since it's actually normal in $G$, which is a stronger property than being normal in $H$ (which it is of course). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I seem to follow you. That's why I had mentioned it in a comment rather than the post itself to emphasize the stronger statement. Thought it might come in handy for the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
This problem is the same problem as Problem 18 on p.48 in Herstein's book.
I solved this problem as follows:

> Let $y\in N$.
> Let $a\in G$.
> Since $y\in N\subset a^{-1}H(a^{-1})^{-1}$, we can write $y=a^{-1}h(a^{-1})^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$.
> Then, $aya^{-1}=aa^{-1}h(a^{-1})^{-1}a^{-1}=h\in H$.
>
> Let $b\in G$.
> Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $G$.
> $byb^{-1}=x(x^{-1}b)y(x^{-1}b)^{-1}x^{-1}\in xHx^{-1}$ since $(x^{-1}b)y(x^{-1}b)^{-1}\in H$.
> So, $byb^{-1}\in N$.
> So, $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.